# Adding pagination to contents

Tags: woocommerce

So, I have following code to display products in Woocommerce

```
<?php
get_header()
?>
<div class="rfp_hide" id="rhm_product_show">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'product_cat' => '',
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product, $userpro, $post, $paged; 
    ?>
    <div class="rhm_indi_product rhm_profile_items">Contents</div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT &raquo;', $loop->max_num_pages) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I am getting `/page/2` but the content does not change and only displays the same stuffs.

Am I doing it right?

Thanks